# Nothing Shows Up on Canvas from SurfaceHolder . lockCanvas() [Android]

Tags: java, android, canvas, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I'm trying to draw on the canvas that is returned from the surface holder's .`lockCanvas()` function but the canvas that is rendered is simply white.

My `MySurface extends SurfaceView` and `implements SurfaceHolder`
The constructor:

```
MySurface(Context context){
            super(context);
            surfaceHolder = getHolder();
            surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
            displayThread = new MyDisplayThread(surfaceHolder);
        }
```

My `surfaceCreated()` override

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder sH){
            displayThread.start();
        }
```

My `surfaceDestroyed()` override

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder sH){
            boolean reset = true;
            while(reset){
                try{
                    displayThread.join();
                    reset = false;
                }catch (InterruptedException e){}
            }
        }
```

And the thread that I use for drawing:
the class variables are:

```
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder,
Paint paint,
boolean isRunning,
Canvas canvas = null


 class MyDisplayThread extends Thread {

        MyDisplayThread(SurfaceHolder sH){
            surfaceHolder = sH;
            isRunning = true;
            paint = new Paint();
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(isRunning){
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                try{
                    myDraw();
                }finally {
                    if(canvas != null) surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }

        public void myDraw(){
            paint.setARGB(255,152,54,12);
            canvas.drawText("RSFDS",100,100,paint);
            canvas.drawRect(120,150,300,300,paint);
            paint.setARGB(255,255,255,255);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (these have worked for me in the past):

Put `setWillNotDraw(false);` inside surfaceCreated

Call `postInvalidate();` on your SurfaceHolder object before drawing each frame.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `getHolder()` again after `surfaceCreated()` is called. That should fix your problem.

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
}
```